# background image not repeating in IE

Tags: css, background-image, repeat

This should be real simple...not sure what I'm not seeing here...the background image repeats just fine in non-IE browsers but fails to in IE8.

site: http://www.erisdesigns.net/Stage/McCampbellInsurance/index.html

```
#wrapper {
    max-width:100%;
    min-width:1000px;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-image:url(images/shadowborder.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:center;
    margin-bottom:-70px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}

#headwrapper {
    position:relative;
    -moz-background-clip:border;
    -moz-background-origin:padding;
    -moz-background-size:auto auto;
    background-image:url(images/btr_rpt.jpg); /* NO REPEAT!!! */
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:150px;
}

#header {
    position:relative;
    -moz-background-clip:border;
    -moz-background-origin:padding;
    -moz-background-size:auto auto;
    background-color:transparent;
    background:url(images/KMIAFS_banner.jpg) center top no-repeat;
    height:150px;
}

#menu {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    border-top:5px solid #003a72;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:70px;
}

#spacer {
    height:70px;
    clear:both;
}

#footer {
    position:relative;
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    border-top:5px solid #003a72;
    background-color:#bec8e3;
    text-align:center;
    color:#666;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:-70px;
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML:

```
</head>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="headwrapper">
<div id="header"></div>
     <div id="menu">
       <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#" title="">/a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title=""></a></li>
       </ul>        
         </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.erisdesigns.net%2FStage%2FMcCampbellInsurance%2Findex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width 100%;` to `#wrapper`

```
#wrapper { width: 100%; }
```

Does it work?

Comment: @snootles always so simple.  I thought, incorrectly, that max-width:100% would take care of that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the failure of the header image to stretch to larger than 1000px? If so, this is due to the size of the element, rather than a background issue.

This appears to be caused by the rule `display: table` on `#wrapper` in the inline stylesheet, which causes shrink-to-fit behaviour, shrinking to the `min-width` of 1000px. This rule makes no sense as the contents of the wrapper are not table row elements. You'd be better off with the header image outside of the fixed-width-centered wrapper and with a plain `width: 100%` to fill the page.

That stylesheet itself is in a downlevel-hidden conditional comment which will affect all versions of IE except 7, which seems a bad idea... is that really what you meant, and what were you trying to achieve with the `display: table` hack? All the `-moz-` rules also seem totally superfluous. This is a simple layout that should not need hacks.

Irrelevant aside: you've also included an XML declaration at the top of the file. It's best to omit this for HTML-compatible-XHTML, as it causes IE6 to fall back to Quirks Mode (even worse rendering than normal for IE6), and in any case, as it specifies only XML 1.0 in UTF-8, which are the defaults anyway, it's pointless. For HTML-compatible-XHTML you should be setting the `charset` parameter to UTF-8 in a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type">` tag instead.

Comment: Well, you should be sending the content type via the server, markup is pointless for this purpose.